# How to improve java project performance?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, jfreechart

I have more than 20M data in MongoDB and by using java driver I try to get data and plot chart by using JFreeChart.

I have simple main class which reads data from MongoDb,creates dataset and plots chart.When I run the program in PC (3GB Ram,i5 processor) it performs very slowly.In 10 hours it only performs 200K data.Then I try to run the code in IBM server with 24 GB RAM but the performance is same.

This is the command that i run :

**java -cp my-program.jar:external1.jar:external2:jar Graph**

Shouldn't it be fast on the server? How could I improve the performance?

Comment: Have you tried giving Java some of that memory? The `-Xmx` and `-Xms` options are worth a look.

Comment: Is there any fancy math involved? I'm charting 200k data points in a matter of seconds...

Comment: Have you worked out where the poor performance is coming from? If you just query the data and throw it away to isolate the data retrieval performance does it still take as long?

Comment: Have you profiled your application?  You should be able to process 200K points in a fraction of second depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Are you loading all of the data into memory to process? You should be able to do a nice group query or map reduce to just grab a summary of data to your Java application.

Comment: Actually i sort the data in mongo and then by reading data i create dataset for jfreechart.creating dataset took much time.inside createDataset method i got 1K sorted data from mongo and add them into dataset.

Comment: Did you try and check the performance of the individual queries? Sorting affects which (if any) indexes are selected. Make sure you run explain() on your query to verify that's not where the problem is. I find it extremely like your issue is related to that and not Java, the driver, your logic or JFreeChart.

Comment: First find bottleneck than try to improve performance. You can add some timestamps to your code to measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.It is not related with the Java, the problem is caused by Jfreechart.

I am sorting data on MongoDB and add data to the [XYSeries](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#XYSeries%28java.lang.Comparable,%20boolean%29) in order to create dataset.
XYSeries has autoSort field in the constructor and by default it is true. That means when you add new item to the dataset it checks whether or not the items in the series are sorted. By setting it false improves the performance.

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("followersCount",false);
```

Secondly, I setted the notify to false in the [add method](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#add%28double,%20double,%20boolean%29). If it is not setted as false, then it sends notification to all registered listeners which reduces performance.

```
series.add(1,2000,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're at the deployment step. So, if you have a web application that will run on a server then you shouldn't just run the app. (.jar)
A Web Applcation Archive (.war) should be created and installed to your container (Tomcat, Glassfish, Weblogic etc.).
After doing these, if you still have performance issues then that points a problem about your  code/logic.